# Show that if $q(x)$ is continuous and $q_{-} \leq q(x) \leq q_{+}$for $x \in[0,2]$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, analysis, dynamical-systems, boundary-value-problem

Consider the boundary value problem (BVP)
$$
\begin{aligned}
&y^{\prime \prime}+q(x) y=\lambda y, x \in[0,2], \\
&y^{\prime}(0)=y^{\prime}(2)=0 .
\end{aligned}
$$
Show that if $q(x)$ is continuous and $q_{-} \leq q(x) \leq q_{+}$for $x \in[0,2]$, then this BVP has a solution for some $\lambda \in\left[q_{-}-1, q_{+}+1\right]$.

I am not getting any idea at all. Can I get a series of hints if not a solution to start?

Answer (score 2):

I'd say use the Sturm-Picone comparison theorem and related ideas. To get a construction going, consider for arbitrary $λ$ the IVP solution $y(x;λ)$ with $y(0;λ)=1$, $y'(0;λ)=0$. Of special interest is the first positive root $z(λ)$ of $y'(x;λ)=0$. Set it to $\infty$ if no such root exists.

Then as a conjectured consequence of the Sturm-Picone theory,

- for $λ=q_++1$ the solution $y(x;λ)$ is convex, looking similar to $\cosh(x)$, supported by the horizontal line $y=1$ (no higher horizontal lines can be tangent). Especially $y'(2)=0$ is impossible.
- For $λ=q_-+1$ you can compare by Sturm-Picone with $\cos x$, so that $z(λ)\in(0,\frac\pi2]$ exists.

Roots $z(λ)$, when finite, depend continuously on $λ$. This first positive root $z(λ)$ thus moves from $\infty$ to below $\frac\pi2$ on the given $λ$ interval, so there has to be a $λ$ in-between where this root is at $z(λ)=2$.

Comment: Ok, here I am. Putting $q_++1$ $
y^{\prime \prime}+(q(x)-( q_++1)) y=0
$ and comparing with $y^{\prime \prime}+(q(x)- \lambda ) y=0$ we can have compare the roots with S-P theorem and similarly with $q_--1$ $ but how do we say that $y;(x) \neq 0$? We can't solve it right?

Comment: Moreover I might miss a detail that S-P theorem(I am seeing this statement https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sturm%E2%80%93Picone_comparison_theorem#:~:text=In%20mathematics%2C%20in%20the%20field,differential%20equations%20in%20the%20real)  says about roots of the solution but here the question is to find the solution of the ODE.

Comment: The proof of S-P is about rotations in the phase space with axes $y$, $y'$, so that claims about root frequencies for $y$ have counterparts for the root frequencies or $y'$.

Comment: Ok, here I am. Putting $_++1$ if $′′+(()−(_++1))=0$ and comparing with $′′+(()−)=0$ we can have the roots with S-P theorem and similarly with $_−−1$ but how do we say that $y'(x) \neq 0$? We can't solve the ODE right?

I am doomed here and also I I don't get your last comment as we have to find the solution of ODE not the root of the solution. Can you give me more hints?

Comment: You compare $y''-(1+q_+-q(x))y=0$ with $y''-y=0$. I'm not actually sure that this occurs regularly in the statement of the S-P theorem, but there is the accompanying statement that $y''-qy=0$ with $q\ge m>0$ can only have solution with at most one root (else at the extremum in-between the signs are wrong).

Comment: I have got $y=Ae^x+Be^{-x}$. Now if we put $y'(0)=y'(2)=0$ we will get $y=0$.  So this can't be the proper boundary condition. So how do we get that the solution is a multiple of the solution we get from $′′+((_++1)-q)=0$ discarding the first possibility that between two roots of  $′′+((_++1)-q)=0$ there would not be a root of the $′′-=0$? Moreover, will this solution align with $q_--1$?

Comment: The most important thing here is that the theorem assumes that the solution exists for both the ODEs and then studying roots or comparing the solutions and the given question asks us to prove that there is a solution for the ODE. Did I understand the question correctly or am I understanding the question wrong?

Comment: Is it possible to fill out all the details? I read the proof of the theorem from http://www.math.iitb.ac.in/~siva/ma41707/ode8.pdf they clearly assume that the solutions are fundamental solutions which exist. Now the problem is that does the solution always exist for $\lambda \in [q_--1,q_++1]$ or am I not understanding the question? What do we need to prove? Please help. It is so complicated.

Comment: You are on the search for eigenvalues $λ$ of the operator on the left side with the given homogeneous boundary conditions. The set of eigenvalues is discrete, all eigenvalues are simple. The claim is that the interval $[q_--1,q_++1]$ contains as least one eigenvalue

Comment: That makes sense now. Then the S-P theorem says that given eigenvalue exists what will the roots of the eigenfunctions be? It is not telling the existence of the eigenvalue.  That is why I am stuck. Can you give me a detailed answer now? Will it be too long for you to type? I am not getting any proper way.

Comment: Thanks for the edit but the parts are still very confusing to me. Of special interest is the first positive root $z(λ)$ of $y'(x;λ)=0$. Set it to $\infty$ if no such root exists. Do we consider the root of $y'$ or $y$?
For $λ=q_++1$ the solution $y(x;λ)$ is convex, looking similar to $\cosh(x)$, supported by the horizontal line $y=1$ (no higher horizontal lines can be tangent). Why is it so?

Comment: Like I failed to connect the dots.

Comment: Yes, I'm not so sure myself for this approach at the moment. The smallest eigenvalue is also the minimum of $\frac12\int_0^2 [-v'(x)^2+q(x)v(x)^2]\,dx$ over all admissible functions with $\int_0^2v(x)^2\,ds=2$. Inserting $v\equiv 1$ gives $λ_\min\le \frac12\int_0^2q(x)\,dx\le q_+$, for $λ_\min\ge q_-$ one could still use that no solution for $λ<q_-$ can exist due to convexity.

Comment: My suspicion is that comparing with $\cos(\pi x/2)$ will give bounds for the second lowest  eigenvalue, what would be required is comparing with $y=1$ as solution of $y''+0·y=0$, but at the moment I do not see how that works with Sturm-Picone.

Comment: +1 Interesting suggestion.